# LocallyConnected1D vs. Dense layer in Keras

Tags: keras

I understand that a LocallyConnected1D layer is the same as 1D conv layer with unshared parameters. But is a LocallyConnected1D layer with 1 filter and kernel_size = 1 essentially the same as a Dense/Fully Connected layer?